# I cannot find pip in Python 3.9.7, find an install that actually works, and it refuses to recognize the pathway I set up for pip

Tags: pip, scripting, python-3.9

I followed several tutorials on how to fix it, made sure pip was check marked when modify installation, tried creating an environment pathway (which I already have one for python) for it but then I realized Scripts were now where to be found. I also tried python -m pip install openpyxl from another 3.9.7 post with the same problem, didn't work. I did some further digging and found it in my lib folder under site-packages. It refuses to recognize it no matter what I do. I Tried creating a pathway for that but it still doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

I tired creating new pathways and to manual install pip

Comment: try to show your error traceback

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.